# How to delete a function from constructor?

Tags: javascript

How to delete a function from constructor?

If there is a function called `greet` in the `Person` constructor, how do I remove the function?

```
function Person(name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.greet = function greet()
    {
        alert("Hello, " + this.name + ".");
    };
}
```

I want the result to be:

```
function Person(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the source of a function. If you want to change that function's behaviour, you have to options:

**Override the function with your own.** This is easy if the function is standalone. Then you can really just define

```
function Person(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```

*after* the original function was defined. But if prototypes and inheritance are involved, it can get tricky to get a reference to the original prototype (because of the way how function declarations are evaluated).

**Ceate a wrapper function** which creates and instance and removes the properties you don't want:

```
function PersonWrapper(name) { 
    var p = new Person(name); 
    delete p.greet; 
    return p;
}
```

This approach is also limited since you can only change what is accessible from the outside. In the example you provided it would be sufficient though.

Answer (score 6):

```
delete this.greet
```

or

```
var personInstance = new Person();
delete personInstance.greet // to remove it from the instance from the outside
```

or

```
delete Person.prototype.greet // if doing prototypes and inheritance
```

`delete` is a keyword that your very rarely see but I assure you, it exists :P

Comment: Surely you mean `delete personInstance.greet`, not `delete Person.greet` (the function does not have a property `greet`).

Comment: What if I want to delete from the constructor when there are no instances?

Comment: @XP1: If there are no instances, then `this.greet` does not exist, since the constructor was never executed. So in this regard your question does not make much sense. Maybe you want to edit the source code or override `Person` with your own function which does not contain this part.

Comment: So every time I instantiate a `Person`, I have to delete the `greet` function? This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @XP1: Then override `Person` with your own function. Or create a wrapper: `function PersonWrapper(name) { var p = new Person(name); delete p.greet; return p;}`... fact is that you cannot change the source of a function.

Comment: Thanks, @Felix Kling! I'll use the wrapper.